# Eclipse automation with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

In Eclipse (Neon) a runnable `.jar` can be created via `File > Export > Runnable jar > Next` and interacting with the dialog that appears. I wanted to eliminate those steps. I automated the export of my `.jar` file by creating the following `ant` file which is called `makeJar.xml` and resides in the project directory.

```
<project name="makeJar" default="makeJarTarget" basedir=".">
    <property name="jar" value="../export/ohana1/ohana1.jar"/>
    <target name="makeJarTarget">
        <jar destfile="${jar}" basedir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target name="cleanTarget">
        <delete file="${jar}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

This `ant` file is visible in the `Project > Properties > Builders` dialog. At the top of the list of builders is the default builder called `Java Builder` and next in the list is this additional builder which is the aforementioned `ant` file and it appears as `makeJar`.

[image: builders dialog]

Assume that at this point an edit to the Java source code happens. The first step of saving any code changes will cause `.class` files to be updated. The next step of clicking `Build All` will update the `.jar` file.

It would be more ideal if saving any code changes (without having to click `Build All`) had that same effect. Unfortunately it does not. Saving code changes results in only `.class` files being updated; the `.jar` will be unchanged (out-of-date).

It is possible to reason why this is the case. In the Eclipse `Project` menu, `Build All` is a choice that is distinct from `Build Automatically`. So if code changes are saved and `Build Automatically` was previously set (this menu item can "remember" a check mark setting) the `.class` files are updated but nothing more than that. There is no menu item to perform something like `Build All Automatically`. Is there any way to further automate so that saving code changes is sufficient to generate not only `.class` files but also the `.jar`?

[image: project menu]

EDIT: Caution: "Build All" has the effect of building all projects that are open. Before clicking "Build All" you might want to close any projects that you are merely browsing.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Navigator* view double-click the file `.project` to open it and remove the line:

```
<triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
```

After the Builder configuration is edited, this has to be done again.

Comment: Sorry to report that that did not work. BTW in my .project file it was <triggers>clean,full,incremental,</triggers>

Comment: And did you uncomment or remove this line? I have verified it with Eclipse Oxygen.1a.

Comment: I removed it. I am on Neon. Anyway, this question is no longer a priority for me. I decided to export manually.